# storing facebook friends - timeout - mysql database

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm working on a simple facebook application where I'm storing:

Facebook friends ID

Table structure:

Table name: facebook_mapping
Values:

```
app_id                fb_id
1               100003996070108
2               100003960002436
3               100003955972927
4               100003955972924
```

using fql query:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=FACEBOOK_USER_ID
```

This works well for friends less than 200. But if a user has more than 200 friends, when I run the application page for the first time, it times out always. I think it takes more than 30 seconds and my server has a constraint that it would timeout after 30 seconds.

I'm using PHP & MySQL. One solution I think is:

1) First only take 20 friends of that user and add it in database
2) Run a background process to gather other friends

Please help me to setup a background process to gather friends or some other method to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s your *PHP script* timing out on inserting the data (and not the API request itself) – then *how exactly* are you adding the data into your table?

Are you firing 200+ individual INSERT statements at your database in a PHP loop or something?

If that’s the case, try putting all the data (or larger chunks of it) into a *multiple row INSERT statement*, in the form of

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
  VALUES (1, '100003996070108'), (2, '100003960002436'), (…)
```

That should help prevent PHP script timeouts, because you don’t have to make so many individual queries to your database.

Comment: yes, we're using in the similar manner. We're not doing an individual insert statements. When I'm querying Facebook, it is taking a bit of time to get all the data and after processing the json output into insert statements, it is taking more than 30 seconds which is causing timeout. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Then you should probably take some measurements first, to make sure which part actually is the time-consuming one … so that you don’t start going at it from a completely useless angle. Put some echos of `microtime` in there, then we’ll work along from that.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the Facebook API, just the timeout that you configured on our server.  The background thread idea is a good one.